# How to query a specific node using Graphql?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, contentful

I am trying to use Graphql to return a specific instance of an object.

This is my Graphql query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allContentfulFlexStyleBody {
    edges {
      node {
        image {
          file {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns 3 Nodes:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allContentfulFlexStyleBody": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "image": {
              "file": {
                "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/m7ipc0qjqa17/6JTBUN3mkENLvEVuC/6ff4b2da441f1c7cec2eb401534aa749/-19.jpeg"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "image": {
              "file": {
                "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/m7ipc0qjqa17/2s6lg5oBJ7F780DI1/b4068dcc9cc889dbcd09ed992793e771/-BTS.png"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "image": {
              "file": {
                "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/m7ipc0qjqa17/6bRRjlI1nLFCdUawZ/12af617d352b21864192dcc033198951/MyStylist_Photo_Grid_Layout__Retouched_Photos_Shortlist-6.jpeg"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I am attempting to display one image within my gatsby project as such:

```
 {data.allContentfulFlexStyleBody.edges.map(({ node }, index) => (
    <img
      className={"contentFeatureImg"}
      alt={``}
      key={``}
      src={node.image.file.url}
    />
  ))}
```

All images are being displayed. How do I access the first, second or third node exclusively without returning the entire edges array?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display just one image? Or do you want to query only a specific image (with for example an id) in the GraphQL server?

Comment: query one image

Comment: Can you inspect the schema? Most likely there is a query where you can receive all the information of one image.

Comment: `...edges[0].node.image.file.url`

Comment: I'm querying contentful from gatsby there is no schema

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a specific element of the edges array works enough for what I'm doing here:

```
  <img
    className={"contentFeatureImg1"}
    alt={``}
    key={``}
    src={data.allContentfulFlexStyleBody.edges[0].node.image.file.url}
  />
```